# cURL Variable inside url

Tags: bash, shell

```sh
getcode=$(curl http://www.fromsomewhere.com/?xxxxx=1) (from an API that returns a number value. eg 5555)

echo $getcode  #5555(able to get #5555)

curl "http://www.fromsomewhere.com/?qs=$getcode&qss=1&qqq=123"
```

I can't really do this as I found the url looks.

```sh
echo "http://www.fromsomewhere.com/?qs=$getcode&qs.condition=1&qqq=123"
```

the output is: `&qs.condition=1&qqq=123e.com/?qs=555`
It replaces the url `http://......`

What is the proper solution to have the url print properly like
`"http://www.fromsomewhere.com/?qs=5555&qs.condition=1&qqq=123"`?

oddly
if I only have

```
http://www.fromsomewhere.com/?qs=$getcode
```

the url looks fine.

however, when I add an `&`
`http://www.fromsomewhere.com/?qs=$getcode&qs.condition...`

then it looks wrong again

Comment: are you running this from a bash script or a shell?

Comment: @naimdjon I am running from bash script

Comment: Could you paste the whole script?

Comment: I've tried this one, and it works as expected:
```getcode=$(curl http://localhost:8000/foo.txt?xxxxx=1)
echo $getcode #5555

echo "http://www.fromsomewhere.com/?qs=$getcode&qss=1&qqq=123"```

Comment: Thanks @naimdjon this is about almost the whole lot. `curl` to get a code from an API. e.g get `5555` then wanted to use the variable in another curl. 

Maybe something wrong from API returned value ... will double check

Comment: Yes, I found static value is ok, and the `variable` inside a url replacing some strings. probably something to do with API not bash ... sorry

Comment: So when you run getcode="#5555" and then run the curl command, everything words as expected?

Comment: Yes! so odd.. @RamanSailopal

Comment: I assume you get a `\r` in your first call: `#5555\r`

Comment: If you run getcode=$(curl http://..... and then echo "$getcode" (note the quotes), do you see anything different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure you get a `\r` at the end in your first curl call.
See example:

```
$ printf -v getcode '5555\r'
$ echo "http://www.fromsomewhere.com/?qs=$getcode&qs.condition=1&qqq=123"
&qs.condition=1&qqq=123e.com/?qs=5555
```

exactly the output you have.

Comment: The solution is to replace `$getcode` with `${getcode%$'\r'}`

Comment: @tripleee Yes! working now! thank you